# How to hand over parameter to a Power Shell script?

Tags: powershell

I have a power shell script to resize some Images. Now I want to handover some parameter from one script to the other to resize all images within a certain folder. What am I doing wrong:

```
Param ( [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [ValidateNotNull()] $imageSource,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [ValidateNotNull()] $imageTarget,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNull()] $quality,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNull()] $canvasWidth,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNull()] $canvasHeight
    )


    if (!(Test-Path $imageSource)){throw( "Cannot find the source image")}
    if(!([System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($imageSource))){throw("please enter a full path for your source path")}
    if(!([System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($imageTarget))){throw("please enter a full path for your target path")}
    if(!([System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($canvasWidth))){throw("please enter your maximum width")}
    if(!([System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($canvasHeight))){throw("please enter your maximum height")}
    if ($quality -lt 0 -or $quality -gt 100){throw( "quality must be between 0 and 100.")}

    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
    $bmp = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($imageSource)

    #hardcoded canvas size...
    #$canvasWidth = 5
    #$canvasHeight = 5

    #Encoder parameter for image quality
    $myEncoder = [System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder]::Quality
    $encoderParams = New-Object System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1)
    $encoderParams.Param[0] = New-Object System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter($myEncoder, $quality)
    # get codec
    $myImageCodecInfo = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo]::GetImageEncoders()|where {$_.MimeType -eq 'image/jpeg'}

    #compute the final ratio to use
    $ratioX = $canvasWidth / $bmp.Width;
    $ratioY = $canvasHeight / $bmp.Height;
    $ratio = $ratioY
    if($ratioX -le $ratioY){
    $ratio = $ratioX
    }

    #create resized bitmap
    $newWidth = [int] ($bmp.Width*$ratio)
    $newHeight = [int] ($bmp.Height*$ratio)
    $bmpResized = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($newWidth, $newHeight)
    $graph = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmpResized)

    $graph.Clear([System.Drawing.Color]::White)
    $graph.DrawImage($bmp,0,0 , $newWidth, $newHeight)

    #save to file
    $bmpResized.Save($imageTarget,$myImageCodecInfo, $($encoderParams))
    $bmpResized.Dispose()
    $bmp.Dispose()
```

The Script I use to execute my script:

```
Get-ChildItem .\img -Recurse -Include *.png | Foreach-Object{
   $newName = $_.FullName.Substring(0, $_.FullName.Length - 4) + "_resized.png"
   .\ImageResize.ps1 $_.FullName $newName 100 3 16
   }
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
> Get-ChildItem : please enter your maximum width In
> C:\Users\me\Desktop\Scripte\Image_Resize\Image.ps1:1 Zeichen:1
> + Get-ChildItem .\img -Recurse -Include *.png | Foreach-Object{
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (please enter your maximum width:String) [Get-ChildItem], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : please enter your maximum width,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: `[System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($canvasWidth)` ehhh, what?

Comment: Ups this happens if you mindlessly copy paste code :-) kind of embarrassing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `[System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($canvasWidth)` makes zero sense. The method is intended to receive a string argument representing a path.

Stop calling [`[System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.ispathrooted(v=vs.110).aspx) with numerical arguments like `$canvasWidth`

---

PowerShell also supports [validation attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714432(v=vs.85).aspx) to simplify input validation, no need for you to do that inline, manually:

```
function Test-ParamValidation {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateScript({[System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($_)})]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateRange(1,500)]
        [int]$Width
    )
}
```

Check out the Scripting Guys post [Simplify Your PowerShell Script with Parameter Validation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/15/simplify-your-powershell-script-with-parameter-validation.aspx)